# When removing element from list of arrays, I encountered an error. Quite confused

Tags: python, arrays, list

Now I have a list of arrays:

```
lis = [array[...], array[....]....]
idx = 1
```

But when I use `lis.remove(list[idx])`, an error arises saying:

> ValueError: 
>   The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` or `a.all()`

I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: What do you think this `list[idx]` does? list is a name of build in python type.

Comment: That error would only be possible if you were using `numpy`. Please show a complete example that produces the error.

Comment: `remove` removes an object from a list by reference to the object itself. If you want to remove the object by its index in the list, perhaps you want `del lis[idx]`

Comment: Is `lis.remove(list[idx])` exactly as you have it in your code?  Because I'm guessing `list[idx]` should be `lis[idx]`.

Comment: Sorry, I just type it wrong. It should be lis.remove(lis[idx])